# PHP Parse Text into Array

Tags: php, parsing

I have an HTML file that I have downloaded using curl and inserted into a string. The HTML file has a lot of content but I am looking to parse a certain section of the document and insert this section into an array. The tricky part of this is that the section that I'm trying to parse is NOT HTML, it's code in JavaScript block:

```
 <!-- script block -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//external.site.com/76b07.js"></script>
 <script>....code.....
 "235533":{"itemId":"235533","type":"0","image":{"url":"thispic.jpg"}:"summary":"This Item"},
 "235534":{"itemId":"235534","type":"1","image":{"url":"thisotherpic.jpg"}:"summary":"This Other Item"},
 </script>
```

How can I import item information as an array?:

```
$array = array( "itemId" => "235533", "type" => "0", "image" => "thispic.jpg", "summary" =>"This Item" );
```

Comment: Is it code or JSON?... see `json_decode`

Comment: string operations to isolate the data, then try passing it to json_decode and see if it's json-valid? (all json is valid javascript, but not all javascript is valid json).

Comment: @j08691: it's a multi-level nested data structure. explode won't do it without lots of extra work.

Comment: @MarcB - oh come on, who among us doesn't love lots of extra work? :P

Comment: It's definitely json. I just have to work on cleaning it up for json_decode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might use a RegExp to match `"....":{....}` located between `<script>` tags. The strings, you're interested in, are [JSON](http://json.org) variables.
Once you have each json variable in a string, you could try with [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
$json_string = '"235533":{"itemId":"235533","type":"0","image":{"url":"thispic.jpg"}:"summary":"This Item"}';
$json = json_decode($json_string);
$myArray = (array)$json;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try json_decode function in php

Answer (score 1):

You would first need to figure out how to isolate the data structure using whatever string searching methodologies you can use that are repeatable even when the data changes.  It is hard to say what this might be without further context from you about the content around the data structure - i.e. what is the same in all cases, and what varies.

You would then eventually get the data strings and `json_decode` them as others have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php). For example, something like

```
$array = explode('","', $string);
```

that would get close to what you want.

**Edit:**
[This](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) looks like a better fit for you.

Answer (score 0):

use regex to match them

```
preg_match_all('/[0-9]+":{"itemId":"(?P<itemId>[0-9]*)","type":"(?P<type>[0-9]{1})","image":{"url":"(?P<image>.*)"}:"summary":"(?P<summary>.*)}/',$mystring,$elements,PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

then loop through $elements to get your values

Comment: added `,PREG_SET_ORDER` to the end to sort as you wanted